# Java getResource() поиск ресурса при наличии JavaAgent

Tags: java

При наличии ресурсов в папке с JAR файлом метод getResource() берет их оттуда
Необходимо, что бы метод getResource() брал ресурсы из JAR файла, а не папки, в которой он запущен
Как это можно сделать?
UPD: Проблема возникает только при присоедененном javaagent

Comment: Попробуйте указать пакетный путь к файлу: `getResource("/pack1/pack2/file.txt")` или попробуйте это: `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(). getResourceAsStream("file.txt");`

Comment: @Jiftoo Используется полный путь `MyClass.class.getResource("/".concat(filename))`

Comment: Попробуйте убрать слеш в начале `MyClass.class.getResource("filename")`

Comment: Программа запускается с JavaAgent. При его отключении все работает корректно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема появляется если приложение и агент находятся в одном JAR файле и приложение запускается так : `java -javaagent:App.jar myapp.Main`
Для исправления нужна такая строка запуска: `java -javaagent:App.jar -cp App.jar myapp.Main`

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю так:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

IOUtils.toString(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt"));
```

file.txt должен лежать в папке web-app/resources в том же пакете что и MyClass.

Comment: У меня подобный код. Проблема в том, что при наличии в папке с jar file.txt он берет его из папки, а не из JAR